# Prove that $f(x)= p(x,a)$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $S$ be a subset of $X$. Define a metric space $(X, p).$ Prove that for any point $a\in X$, function $f: S \to\mathbb R$, where $f(x)= p(x,a)$ is continuous.

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the definition of continuity; where are you having trouble?

Comment: I have trouble seeing how it is an immediate consequence of definition of continuity. Definition of continuity: If f: s maps to R is continuous at c in S, for all epsilon > 0, there exists an r>0: f(B$_r$(a)) is a subset of B$_e$(f(c))

Comment: A very little fiddling with the triangle inequality shows you that $f^{-1}[B_\epsilon(f(x))]=B_\epsilon(x)$, i.e., that $p(x,y)<\epsilon$ if and only if $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Specifically, if $p(x,y)<\epsilon$, then $f(y)=p(y,a)\le p(y,x)+p(x,a)<f(x)+\epsilon$ and $f(x)=p(x,a)\le p(x,y)+p(y,a)<f(y)+\epsilon$, so $f(x)-\epsilon<f(y)<f(x)+\epsilon$.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

From the triangular inequality:
$$
|p(x,a)-p(y,a)| \leq p(x,y),
$$
and you conclude.

Comment: It is true that $ p(x,a)-p(y,a)\leq p(x,y)$. But I dont know how to show why does the absolute value hold?

Comment: The inequality is symmetric in $x$ and $y$.